# How can i create dynamic variables on the fly in c# using Reflection?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, reflection

I'm creating a simulator of ecosystems where species can be used to simulate various diseases, my problem is that I start using 4 species but if I need more ... I need more variables to store, my question is, Is there any way through Reflection to let me create dynamic variables during the execution of an event in my program? Thank you! i'm using Windows Presentation Foundation and C#

Comment: You don't need more variables. Just one `List<Specie>` is enough.

Comment: you might want to re ask this question describing the problem you are trying to model.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to handle this is to have a base class for your disease species and then use a collection to hold them all:

```
public abstract class DiseaseBase
{
    public abstract void Spread();
}

public class Anthrax : DiseaseBase
{
    public override void Spread()
    {
        GetPostedToPolitician();
    }
}

public class BirdFlu : DiseaseBase
{
    public override void Spread()
    {
        Cluck();
        SneezeOnHuman();
    }
}

public class SwineFlu : DiseaseBase
{
    public override void Spread()
    {
        //roll in mud around other piggies
    }
}

public class ManFlu : DiseaseBase
{
    public override void Spread()
    {
        //this is not contagious
        //lie in bed and complain
        //get girlfriend to make chicken soup
        //serve chicken soup with beer and baseball/football/[A-Za-z0-9]+Ball
    }
}

public List<DiseaseBase> DiseaseCollection = new List<Disease>();
```

So everything gets stored in the collection as the base class (DiseaseBase), and with the appropriate use of abstract methods in the base and/or interfaces you can always handle each disease instance as the base object.

Comment: `NastyDiseaseOne `?!!

Comment: @PoweredByOrange It's a recently discovered disease.. and its nasty.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm thinking a nice disease smackdown game is being built here. If I was building it the diseases would be so badass they would need separate collections to keep them apart in the codebase :)

Comment: @slugster But your example has all diseases in a single collection! You've doomed us all with your example!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm gonna take the top off that collection and let them bubble over unless you pay me.... ONE MILLION DOLLARS. Bwahahahahaha.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange After deciding that `NastyDiseaseOne` was too alarming for the general population to know about and was likely to induce mass panic I decided to update my example.

Comment: @slugster +1 just for your variable/type names.